# 'New' label on app icon - springboard bug or developer corner case?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, app-store

I tested the following:

1. Download v1.0 of my app from the app store
2. Do **not** launch it
3. Run v1.1 from Xcode.
4. Stop Xcode.
5. Return to home screen

I found that the 'new' label remains on my app icon regardless of how many times I launch it.

Now I can't easily test that this would happen if **both** versions were downloaded from the app store (i.e. download v1.0, do not launch, wait for v1.1, install update, launch). But can anyone else verify this behavior and/or shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

> I found that the 'new' label remains on my app icon regardless of how many times I launch it.

Then the 'new' label probably doesn't disappear on launch. Perhaps it disappears on touch.

Comment: I'm launching it my touching it after the initial simulator run.